# How can I start the eventserver?

Tags: ruby, predictionio

I have installed predictionio through brew on my osx ( Maverick ) and i can start the admin's service (`http://0.0.0.0:9000` ) and the api's server (`http://0.0.0.0:8000`).

But reading the docs, with the ruby's sdk, says:

```
# Create a client object.
client = PredictionIO::EventClient.new(<ACCESS KEY>, <URL OF EVENTSERVER>)
```

At first, i have inserted the api's url, but reading other docs ( like the python's sdk ) says that the eventserver runs on `http://0.0.0.0:7070`.

If i try to create a event:

```
client.create_event('rate', 'user', rate.user_id, { 'targetEntityType'=> 'item', 'targetEntityId' => rate.rateable_id, 'properties'=> {'rating'=> 3 }})
```

it always return the same response: 'PredictionIO::EventClient::NotCreatedError: Your request is not supported'

The guide says that the command to run this server is: 
    pio eventserver

But I don't have this bin. I start everything with the script 'predicitonio-start-all.sh' but with this I can't start this event server.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Homebrew script is maintained by community and has not yet been updated to 0.8.4 yet. It is using 0.7.3 (http://braumeister.org/formula/predictionio) which does not work with the current documentation.

Please follow the instructions here to install the latest version: http://docs.prediction.io/install/